# A linearly dependent matrix whose set of rows is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the 2 by 2 square matrix whose entries are all the number $1$. Clearly, both the rows and column are linearly dependent. However, the set of rows(as well as the set of columns) is simply the singleton $\{(1,1)\}$, which is linearly independent. So, what is going on? Can someone clarify this issue for me?

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about a set of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ being linearly independent, we do allow some of the vectors to be the same. (So the usage of the term "set" is a little different than in other contexts where it does not allow duplicates.)

So you ask whether the columns of a matrix are linearly independent or not, you should keep columns that appear more than once.

Comment: So, it is not a set then, but a multiset.